# how to get floor number or suite from google maps API with lat longs

Tags: javascript, geolocation, maps, bing

I have implemented Google maps autocomplete address API , and in the response of that API I am  getting lat longs but what I need is floor number or suite  as well with lat longs , this is because  one building can  have multiple organisation at multiple floors, etc
Right?

so is there any method to achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you need is the [Reverse Geocoding (Address Lookup)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse).
You'll have to pass the received coordinates to the geocode method of the geocoder which will return the address data you're looking for (check out the linked example).

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the return type in the `types` array in your `options` argument when creating the `Autocomplete` object. I think the `address` type will return a floor number too.

> address instructs the Places service to return only geocoding results
> with a precise address.

More information can be found here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete